# Mysql connection works exept for SELECT * INTO OUTFILE statment

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My website works fine except when I execute back-up function for mysql it throws this error :

> SQLSTATE[28000]: Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/archive/db-backup-date-09-09-2015-time-10-30-04/accounts.csv' FROM accounts)

i tried this statment :

```
GRANT FILE ON \*.\* TO 'username'@'localhost'
```

but it throws another error

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'myHostingUserName'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

note that in this error it the user for who access is denied is my hosting user name (hostgator), but I don't have MySql user with this name

Answer (score 0):

Actually mysql does not rights outside so you need to export your file within mysql, you can use as per below-

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/accounts.csv' FROM accounts;
```

assuming /tmp is a directory where mysql is creating temp files.

Also aussing that your csv creation command is fine for you as you are not managing fields seperation etc. issues in it.

Regarding 2nd error, you don't have permission to grand rights.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my local enviorment the script worked fine, and how can I find the directory where I can place my .csv file?

Comment: get your temp dir by "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir'" and you can use this path to save but this is temporary path so you have to move from here otherwise file can be lost from here. other wise you can save in data directory which is also not a good suggestion. You can create one backup directory and can give permission on that directory to mysql and save your csv here.

Comment: I did 'tempdir' but It didn't show me the full path, I couldn't find the directory, But how can I give permission on a directory for mysql? is there a command?

Comment: did you check by SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir'

Comment: Yes I did SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir' , but it didn't show me the full path so I couldn't find the directory

Comment: what it is showing...you can also try to create a backup directory and give permission to mysql like "chown -R mysq.mysql /your_backup_directory"...or you can keep in your data dir like "/var/lib/mysql" but need to keep watch as it can be risky....

Comment: Thank you Zafar, I'll try it, but I have contacted the support and they say the function is not supported on shared plan

Comment: Then you can export in temp and move from here...check your temp location by "SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir'" check  from root (admin) user, you can also check in your configuration file my.cnf (linux) or my.ini (windows) if not mention in config file then it will be /tmp so you can give path just as /tmp/file.csv